# How do I remove the action of a menu.xml item?

Tags: admin, magento-2.2.5, menu.xml

Using Magento 2.2.5.

I have an 3rd party extension admin menu item that should be a header, but has an `action` so is rendering as a link (which 404s). Is there a way to override the `menu.xml` item and remove the `action` property?

In my custom module I have basically the same definition but removing the `action` property:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <update id="Third_Party::menu" title="Succesfully overriding the title" module="Third_Party" sortOrder="101" parent="Magento_Catalog::catalog" resource="Third_Party::menu" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

While my custom module's `menu.xml` update is being picked up and the `title` is changing, the xml is inheriting the `action` property from the `Third_Party/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml` file.

Comment: did you try this in your menu.xml `<update id="Third_Party::menu" title="Succesfully overriding the title" module="Third_Party" sortOrder="101" parent="Magento_Catalog::catalog" resource="Third_Party::menu" action="" />`

Comment: thx !@ShashankKumrawat - Changing action to "" gave me this error: Element 'update', attribute 'action': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'typeAction'.

Comment: put `action` in `#`

Comment: That gives me 'Element 'update', attribute 'action': [facet 'pattern'] The value '#' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9/_]{3,}'.'

Comment: did you find the solution yet? i'm stuck in this for 3 hours ..thanks.